# Can't get first instance of CSS element to line up correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a timeline type page using CSS and I'm having an issue setting the position of the first entry. See the screenshot here:

[image: CSS element off-center]

I'm terrible at setting up CSS sheets and I've tried tinkering with this one but I just cannot seem to get the position of that first element set up the way I want.

HTML here:

```
<!-- The Timeline -->

<ul class="timeline">

    <!-- Item 1 -->
    <li>
        <div class="direction-r">
            <div class="flag-wrapper">
                <span class="flag">Freelancer</span>
                <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">2013 - present</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">My current employment. Way better than the position before!</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <!-- Item 2 -->
    <li>
        <div class="direction-l">
            <div class="flag-wrapper">
                <span class="flag">Apple Inc.</span>
                <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">2011 - 2013</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">My first employer. All the stuff I've learned and projects I've been working on.</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <!-- Item 3 -->
    <li>
        <div class="direction-r">
            <div class="flag-wrapper">
                <span class="flag">Harvard University</span>
                <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">2008 - 2011</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">A description of all the lectures and courses I have taken and my final degree?</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="direction-l">
            <div class="flag-wrapper">
                <span class="flag">Apple Inc.</span>
                <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">2011 - 2013</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">My first employer. All the stuff I've learned and projects I've been working on.</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <!-- Item 3 -->
    <li>
        <div class="direction-r">
            <div class="flag-wrapper">
                <span class="flag">Harvard University</span>
                <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">2008 - 2011</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">A description of all the lectures and courses I have taken and my final degree?</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="direction-l">
            <div class="flag-wrapper">
                <span class="flag">Apple Inc.</span>
                <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">2011 - 2013</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">My first employer. All the stuff I've learned and projects I've been working on.</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <!-- Item 3 -->
    <li>
        <div class="direction-r">
            <div class="flag-wrapper">
                <span class="flag">Harvard University</span>
                <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">2008 - 2011</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">A description of all the lectures and courses I have taken and my final degree?</div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

And style sheet here:

```
/* ================ The Timeline ================ */

.timeline {
  position: relative;
  width: 660px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 1em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.timeline:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  background: rgb(80,80,80);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(80,80,80,0) 0%, rgb(80,80,80) 8%, rgb(80,80,80) 92%, rgba(80,80,80,0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(80,80,80,0) 0%, rgb(80,80,80) 8%, rgb(80,80,80) 92%, rgba(80,80,80,0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(80,80,80,0) 0%, rgb(80,80,80) 8%, rgb(80,80,80) 92%, rgba(80,80,80,0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(80,80,80,0) 0%, rgb(80,80,80) 8%, rgb(80,80,80) 92%, rgba(80,80,80,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(80,80,80,0) 0%, rgb(80,80,80) 8%, rgb(80,80,80) 92%, rgba(80,80,80,0) 100%);

  z-index: 5;
}

.timeline li {
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.timeline li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.direction-l {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}

.direction-r {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}

.flag-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  text-align: center;
}

.flag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  background: rgb(248,248,248);
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
}

.direction-l .flag {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.direction-r .flag {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.direction-l .flag:before,
.direction-r .flag:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -36px;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255,80,80);
  z-index: 10;
}

.direction-r .flag:before {
  left: -83px;
}

.direction-l .flag:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-left-color: rgb(248,248,248);
  border-width: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.direction-r .flag:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-right-color: rgb(248,248,248);
  border-width: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;

}

.time-wrapper {
  display: inline;

  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 0.66666em;
  color: rgb(250,80,80);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.direction-l .time-wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.direction-r .time-wrapper {
  float: right;
}

.time {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  background: rgb(248,248,248);
}

.desc {
  margin: 1em 0.75em 0 0;

  font-size: 0.77777em;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.direction-r .desc {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0.75em;
}

/* ================ Timeline Media Queries ================ */

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {

.timeline {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4em 0 1em 0;
}

.timeline li {
    padding: 2em 0;
}

.direction-l,
.direction-r {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;

    text-align: center;
}

.flag-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.flag {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    z-index: 15;
}

.direction-l .flag:before,
.direction-r .flag:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
    left: 50%;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-left: -9px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 4px solid rgb(255,80,80);
    z-index: 10;
}

.direction-l .flag:after,
.direction-r .flag:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -8px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin-left: -8px;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-width: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.time-wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 14;
}

.direction-l .time-wrapper {
    float: none;
}

.direction-r .time-wrapper {
    float: none;
}

.desc {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background: rgb(245,245,245);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);

  z-index: 15;
}

.direction-l .desc,
.direction-r .desc {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em 1em 0 1em;
    padding: 1em;

  z-index: 15;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px ?? max-width: 660px) {

.direction-l .desc,
.direction-r .desc {
    margin: 1em 4em 0 4em;
}

}
```

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please make a fiddle for this?

Comment: Your code is not complete, please create [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2apzxe0/).

Comment: See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/h2apzxe0/3/

Now I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your css with positions left / right:

```
.direction-l .flag:before,
.direction-r .flag:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -40px;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255,80,80);
  z-index: 10;
}

.direction-r .flag:before {
  left: -40px;
}
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/buaa4zuk/

To be sure, always separate positions. Its more clear if you define it like this:

```
.direction-l .flag:before,
.direction-r .flag:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255,80,80);
  z-index: 10;
}
.direction-l .flag:before
{
    right: -40px;
}
.direction-l .flag:before
{
    left: -40px;
}
```